# SealedObject size error for big string more than 110 bytes

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, key-pair

I make example of rsa encryption and decryption. I cannot decrypt if message larger than 110 bytes. But error say; data must not be longer than 117 bytes. Why 7 bytes can not be used ?

My Class :

```
public class RSAEx {

    static Cipher cipher;
    static KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
    static KeyPair keyPair;
    static String message = "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";

    public static void main(String[] ars) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decryptIt(encryptIt());
    }

    static byte[] encryptIt() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
        SealedObject encryptedMessage = new SealedObject(message, cipher);
        System.out.println("Encrypt Alg : "+encryptedMessage.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Encrypted Msg : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded().length; i++){
            System.out.print(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    }

    static void decryptIt(byte[] encryptedMessage) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
        System.out.println("Decrypted Msg : "+new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage)));
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at javax.crypto.SealedObject.<init>(SealedObject.java:170)
    at com.mimcrea.metronic_ui_android.RSAEx.encryptIt(RSAEx.java:35)
    at com.mimcrea.metronic_ui_android.RSAEx.main(RSAEx.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using older version of java with RSA key size 1024? At my computer with java 8 it 2048 key size the maximum is 245 bytes.

It is the key size /8 - padding which is  11 bytes. So here I get the exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes

2048 / 8 - 11 = 245 bytes

For you it is 1024 key size -> 1024/8 - 11 = 117

The problem is with your code where you do the sealed object. That sealedobject probably carries some overhead because of the cypher which is 7 bytes. If you try your code like that:

```
static Cipher cipher;
    static KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
    static KeyPair keyPair;
    static String message = "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";

    public static void main(String[] ars) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decryptIt(encryptIt());
    }

    static byte[] encryptIt() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
        System.out.println("Size:"+message.getBytes().length);
        return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    }

    static void decryptIt(byte[] encryptedMessage) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
        System.out.println("Decrypted Msg : "+new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage)));
    }
```

Without creating the SealedObject (since you don't use it anyway) you will be able to cypher and decypher exactly 117 bytes.

Comment: It's working. Your answer is very explanatory. Thank you.